# Arreglo binario y no binario: Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 0

Tags: java

CONTEXTO: Este ejercicio ya lo solucioné basándome en el video de PROGRAMACIÓN ATS (Alejandro Taboada), que básicamente es separar de un arreglo los elementos, pares e impares, pero ahora debe ser con elementos binarios 1 y 0, solo cambié la condición `if` a `((arreglo5[i]==1) || (arreglo5[i]==0))`

Código sin funciones (métodos), este código no genera ningún error.

```
    package arreglosNumBinarios2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArreglosNumBinarios {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner leer= new Scanner (System.in);
        
        //Arreglo para 5 elementos
        int arreglo5[] =new int [5];
        int contbin=0, contnobin=0;
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese 5 números binarios");
        
        //Iterador para almacenar los 5 elementos en el arreglo
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            
            //Entrada de datos
            System.out.println("Ha ingresado " + (i+1) + " elemento(os)");
            arreglo5[i]=leer.nextInt();
            
            //Condicion para contabilizar binarios, todo dentro del bucle for
            if ((arreglo5[i]==0) || (arreglo5[i]==1)) {
                
                //contar binarios, sirve para determinar el largo del arreglo
                contbin++;
                
            //Si no
            } else {
                
                System.err.println("Solo debes introducir números binarios, no se agregará al arreglo binario");
                //contar no binarios
                contnobin++;
                
            }//end else

        }//end for
        
    //Arreglo para los binarios y no binarios
        
    //El tamaño del arreglo variará de acuerdo al numero de elementos binarios
        int bin[] = new int [contbin];
    //El tamaño del arreglo variará de acuerdo al numero de elementos no binarios
        int nobin[] = new int [contnobin];
        
    //Cumple función como iterador para evitar el error de la repeticion de la variable i del iterador
    contbin=0; //es como una variable j
    contnobin=0;//es como una variable k
    
    
    //Almacenar los binarios y no binarios en su respectivo arreglo
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        
        //Si son binarios
        if ((arreglo5[i]==0) || (arreglo5[i]==1)) {
            
            //Guardar los numeros binarios en la variable i del arreglo
            bin[contbin]= arreglo5[i];
            
            /**aumentar en 1 el coteo de los numeros binarios para despues usar este valor para 
             * para poder crear el arreglo con valor de la cantidad de numeros binarios que hay en
             * este arreglo
             * */
            contbin++;
            
            //Si no
        } else {
            
            //Guardar los numeros no binarios en la variable i del arreglo
            nobin[contnobin]=arreglo5[i];
            
            /**aumentar en 1 el coteo de los numeros no binarios para despues usar este valor para 
             * para poder crear el arreglo con el valor de la cantidad de numeros no binarios que hay en
             * este arreglo
             * */
            contnobin++;
            
        }//end else
        
    }//end for
    
    
    //Para imprimir binarios
    
    System.out.println("\nArreglo con elementos binarios:");
    
    //Iterador para los elementos binarios
    for (int i =0; i<contbin; i++) {
        
        System.out.println("["+bin[i] + "] " + (i+0) + " Posición");
        
    }//end for imprimir binarios 
    
    //Para imprimir no binarios
    
    System.out.println("\nArreglo con elementos no binarios:");
    
    //Iterador para los elementos no binarios
    for (int i =0; i<contnobin; i++) {
        
        System.out.println("["+nobin[i] + "] " + (i+0) + " Posición");
        
        }//for imprimir no binarios
            
        }//end main
    
    }//end class
```

Muy bien todo hasta ahí, pero cuando empiezo aplicar programación orientada a objetos, es decir, cuando ya aplico funciones (separando el algoritmo por métodos), es cuando me sale el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **Index 5 out of bounds for length 0**
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.arreglosBin_NoBin(Arreglo_binario.java:55)
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.llenarArreglo(Arreglo_binario.java:45)
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.main(Arreglo_binario.java:8

**Código con los métodos separados (aquí sí genera error).**

```
    package arreglo_binario;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arreglo_binario {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        llenarArreglo();
    }

    public static void llenarArreglo() {
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int a[]=new int [5];
        int contbin=0, contnobin=0;
        
        
        //Crear arreglos de acuerdo con el numero de elementos binarios o no binarios
        int bin[]= new int [contbin];
        int nobin[] = new int [contnobin];
        
        //crear for para llenar arreglo
        for (int i= 0; i<5; i++) {
            
            System.out.println("Ha ingresado " + (i+1) + " elemento(os)");
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
            
            //Separar elementos binarios o no binarios
            if ((a[i]==1) || (a[i]==0)) {
                
            //Contar la cantidad de elementos binarios, sirve para determinar el largo del arreglo
                contbin++;
                
            }else{
            
            //Contar la cantidad de elementos NO binarios, sirve para determinar el largo del arreglo
            System.err.println("Solo debes ingresar elementos binarios");
                contnobin++;
    
            }
            
        }//end for
        
        arreglosBin_NoBin(a, contbin, contnobin, bin, nobin);
        
    }//end llenar arreglo
    
    public static void arreglosBin_NoBin(int a[], int contbin, int contnobin, int bin[], int nobin[]) {
        
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        
        if ((a[i]==1) || (a[i]==0)) {
                
        bin[contbin]=a[i];
            contbin++;
        
        //Contar la cantidad de elementos binarios, sirve para determinar el largo del arreglo
        
        } else {
                
        nobin[contnobin]=a[i];
            contnobin++;
        
            }
        
        }//end for
        
        mostrarArreglos(a, contbin, contnobin, bin, nobin);
        
    }//end arreglosbin_Nobin
    
    public static void mostrarArreglos(int a[], int contbin, int contnobin, int bin[], int nobin[]) {
        
        System.out.println("Arreglo binario");
        
        for (int i=0; i<contbin; i++) {
            
            System.out.println("["+ bin[i] +"] " + (i+0) + " Posicion");
            
        }//end for binarios
        
        System.out.println("Arreglo no binario");
        
        for (int i=0; i<contnobin; i++) {
            
            System.out.println("["+ nobin[i] +"] " + (i+0) + " Posicion");
            
        }//end for no binarios
        
       }//end mostrarArreglos
    }//end class
```

**¿Por qué dice que tiene largo 0, si se supone que el largo del arreglo depende de los n elementos que el usuario ingrese?**

El error del index varía dependiendo n elementos binarios que ingreso, por ejemplo si pongo 4 números binarios y luego un elemento no binario sale, `Index 4 out of bounds for length 0.` nótese que ahora dice 4 en lugar de 5.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **Index 4 out of bounds for length 0**
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.arreglosBin_NoBin(Arreglo_binario.java:55)
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.llenarArreglo(Arreglo_binario.java:45)
> at arreglo_binario.Arreglo_binario.main(Arreglo_binario.java:8)

No sé a qué se deba que el flujo del algoritmo "pierde" la información que determina el largo del arreglo.

A continuación 2 preguntas:

1. ¿Cómo soluciono esto; por qué me dice que el largo es de 0?
2. ¿Por qué no imprime en pantalla los arreglos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¡Problema solucionado con métodos!**

> Ha pasado un tiempo, ahora puedo responder esta pregunta.

**Lista de errores**

Para quienes deseen entender qué es lo que estaba mal.

**1.-** Uno de los principales errores que tenía es que al declarar e instanciar los arreglos lo hacía antes que los contadores aumentaran su valor, además, esto hacía que al pasarlos como parámetros el largo de estos dos arreglos fuera de 0, **¡por eso decía *Index 5 out of bounds for length 0!***
Esto significa que los arreglos binario y no binario tuvieran un largo de 0, por lo tanto, no podrían almacenar ningún elemento del arreglo "a".

**2.-** Había un problema de lógica: la función para llenar los arreglos no era aprovechada para llenar los arreglos binario y no binario; ahora en el código que he adjuntado sí es aprovechada esta área del código.

Se debe emplear un `for` con dos variables de control y una condición para llenar los arreglos binario y no binario (explicación del porqué en el código).

**Código**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Problema:
     * Crear un programa que pida ingresar 5 números binarios
     * (0 y 1) y ponerlos en un arreglo de acuerdo a la cantidad
     * de números binarios ingresados, en caso de que no sean
     * binarios mandar mensaje de error de que solo debe de
     * ingresar números binarios, los números no binarios deben
     * ser agregados en otro arreglo.
     *
     * Esto se debe de hacerse con funciones y fuera del método
     * main.
     * */

    //Se llama a la función llenarArreglos();
    llenarArreglos();
}

//Método para llenar los arreglos.
public static void llenarArreglos() {

    byte contBin = 0, contNoBin = 0;

    /*
     * Declaración e instanciación del arreglo auxiliar, almacenará todos los
     * números ingresados.
     * */
    int[] arrAux = new int[5];

    /*
     * Aquí se declaran los arreglos arrBin (binario) y arrNoBin (no binario)
     * pero no se instancian cuantos elementos contendrán.
     */
    int[] arrBin, arrNoBin;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresa 5 números binarios");

    /*
     * El arreglo auxiliar servirá para almacenar los números
     * ingresados sin importar si son binarios o no, lo importante
     * es que por cada número 0 o 1 se registre cuantos elementos
     * se han ingresado, lo mismo con el caso contrario (si
     * no son binarios) para así asignar a los otros 2 arreglos
     * la cantidad de elementos que contendrán.
     * */

    for (byte i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el " + (i + 1) + " número ");

        /*
         * try-catch funciona para evitar que el programa termine (de hecho si termina, pero
         * para eso está la parte de llamar de nuevo a la función desde el catch) por alguna
         * excepción de ingreso de datos por ejemplo, si se ingresa un dato del tipo carácter
         * y no del tipo numérico.
         *
         * La parte try (intentar) tendrá la parte donde se ingresarán los datos y
         * comprobará que sean del tipo entero (int).
         * La parte catch (capturar) tendrá la parte donde vuelve a llamar el método
         * para comenzar de nuevo (recursividad) en caso de que los datos sean incorrectos.
         *
         * */

        try {
            //Se guardan los valores ingresados en el arreglo auxiliar (arrAux)
            arrAux[i] = sc.nextInt();

            //Si son binarios hacer que el contador contBin sume + 1
            if (arrAux[i] == 0 || arrAux[i] == 1) {
                contBin++;
            } else {
                /*Caso contario, mandar mensaje de error y hacer que el contador
                 * contNoBin sume + 1 */
                System.err.println("Solo debes de ingresar 0 y 1, los demás números " +
                        "se agregarán en otro arreglo");
                contNoBin++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.err.println("Solo debes de ingresar números binarios o enteros");
            llenarArreglos(); // Se vuelve a llamar el método desde el mismo método (recursividad)
        }
    }

    /*
     * Aquí se instancia cuantos elementos tendrá cada arreglo.
     * Como dato extra cuando se instancia un arreglo los espacios que
     * tiene para sus elementos se inicializan en 0 si son del tipo
     * numérico no decimal y si son decimal en 0.0 o 0,0 (dependiendo
     * de tu sistema operativo) y si son del tipo de dato Object (de
     * referencia) como el String o Wrapper (que envuelven a un tipo
     * de dato primitivo), sus elementos serán de valor null
     *
     * Con el contador para binarios tiene cuantos elementos
     * contendrá el arreglo para los números binarios la misma
     * lógica aplica para el arreglo de los no binarios
     *                   |
     *                   v       */
    arrBin = new int[contBin];
    arrNoBin = new int[contNoBin];

    byte j = 0, k = 0; //variables de control

    /*
     * Por cada iteración las variables de control aumentarán en 1
     * esto permitirá que se acceda a las posiciones de los arreglos
     * binario (arrBin) y no binario (arrNoBin). Una vez que se
     * tiene su posición se les asignará de acuerdo a la condición
     * if los valores que están dentro del arreglo auxiliar (arrAux)
     *
     * La variable i funciona para recorrer el arreglo auxiliar.
     * */

    for (byte i = 0; i < arrAux.length; i++) {
        /* Si el elemento es 0 o 1 del arreglo auxiliar
         * asignarlo al arreglo binario
         * */
        if (arrAux[i] == 0 || arrAux[i] == 1) {
            arrBin[j++] = arrAux[i];
        } else {
            //Caso contario al arreglo no binario
            arrNoBin[k++] = arrAux[i];
        }
    }

    /*
     * Una vez que se tienen los arreglos, el paso siguiente es mostrarlos
     * en pantalla, se llama a la función mostrarArreglos(); Los parámetros
     * deben ser el arreglo binario, no binario, y sus respectivos
     * contadores (counters).
     * */
    mostrarArreglos(arrBin,arrNoBin, contBin, contNoBin);
}

//Método para mostrar los arreglos
public static void mostrarArreglos(int[] arrBin, int[] arrNoBin, byte contBin, byte contNoBin) {

    /*
     * Los contadores son solo para hacer una condición y mostrar los
     * arreglos y los mensajes, si el contador de binarios es 0 entonces
     * solo se mostrará un mensaje de que no hay números binarios, lo mismo
     * para el arreglo de no binarios.
     *
     * Si los contadores son mayores que 0, entonces se mostrarán los
     * arreglos
     * */

    if (contBin > 0) {

        System.out.println("\nArreglo binario");

        for (byte i = 0; i < arrBin.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + arrBin[i] + "] ");
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("\nNo hay números binarios que mostrar");
    }

    if (contNoBin > 0) {

        System.out.println("\nArreglo no binario");

        for (byte i = 0; i < arrNoBin.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("[" + arrNoBin[i] + "] ");
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("\n\nNo hay números no binarios que mostrar");
    }
    //Si todos los procesos salieron bien, entonces finalizar con status 0, 0 errores
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Error corregido

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo esto al comienzo

```
   int contbin=0, contnobin=0;
        
        
        //Crear arreglos de acuerdo con el numero de elementos binarios o no binarios
        int bin[]= new int [contbin];
        int nobin[] = new int [contnobin];
```

Defines esas variables en cero y luego inicializas los arrays. Esos arrays, como te dice el error en *perfecto español* (not really) tienen tamaño cero porque así los definiste.

Tienes opciones como usar otro tipo de estructura que puedas cambiar de tamaño dinámicamente (no sé, ¿un ArrayList? la elegirías de acuerdo a tus necesidades) o declaras esos arrays en otro punto del algoritmo, cuando ya sepas de qué tamaño los necesitas.

Edit: Si cambias la declaración, también debes revisar cómo accedes a los elementos en los arrays. Usas variables globales pero no validas su contenido en un momento dado y eso te expone a problemas.

Por ejemplo, en un método tienes

```
nobin[contnobin]=a[i];
contnobin++;
```

Y sin hacerle debug, no me atrevería a asegurar que esa variable `contnobin` no esté en 5 para algún escenario de prueba (y si tu array es de tamaño 5, las posiciones van de 0 a 4). Cuando usas índices diferentes a la variable en el for, debes ser cuidadoso con su rango de valores posibles.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfabravo, aunque los inicializo en 5 (porque solo deben ingresar 5 elementos, sin importar si son binarios o no), me sale un error similar, sin embargo, esto me ha ayudado para visualizar mejor como esta funcionando mi código, aclaro que me cuesta trabajo porque soy un estudiante y me falta mucho para ser un profesional.

Sinceramente, se me dificulta ver donde más podría declarar esos arrays, ya chequé unos videos de como usar los array list, pero implementarlos todavía no lo comprendo al 100. 

Muchas gracias por responder, esta comunidad es de gran ayuda :D

Comment: @ErwingBenavides respuesta editada con algunas aclaraciones adicionales.

Comment: @ErwingBenavides, la manera más útil de agradecer una respuesta que te haya servido es aceptarla como respuesta si es la más útil de todas las propuestas, igual puedes votar arriba si te ha gustado lo suficiente

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Disculpa por la gran demora en responder, no es lo que no haya hecho, lo puse como voto positivo aunque debido a que solo he publicado esto, no tengo la reputación suficiente como para hacer que se muestre "visible".